# loop to tally the order weights per order #

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpgle

I am stumped at the moment. What I have to do is, when the main loop is reading an order which is aaord#, we need to tally in this subroutine all the rest of the order rows which has a box weight. the shipping table is like this: for the output, we can put the ord_wt on each row, I can't think of any other way.

```
PHORD#  PHWGHT  PHBNO#
04924920    1.05    1
05012409    27.40   2
05012409    27.40   3
05012409    27.40   4
05012409    27.40   5
05012409    27.40   6
05012409    27.40   7
05012409    27.40   8
05012409    20.00   9
05012421    26.90   2
05012421    26.90   3
05012421    26.90   4
05012430    13.70   2
05036997    21.60   1
05036997    21.60   2
05036997    21.60   3
05036997    21.60   4
05037155    14.55   1
05037173    12.25   1
05037173    12.20   2
05039479    8.10    1
```

so in this code, what I want to do is see if the order number is not = to previous order number, then I will do this code to tally up all the order weights from the ship table. I also need to clear the holding field when there is such a new order number.\ but my output is only zeros in the ord_wt

```
 c                   eval      mhcmno4= aacom#                         
c*                  eval      wkrel@ = %EDITC(aarel#:'X')             
c*                  eval      wkrel2 = %subst(wkrel@:4:2)             
c                   eval      mhordr4 = aaord#                        
c                   eval      wkvsf='N'                               
c*                  endif                                             
c                   z-add     0             phwtno            702       
c*                                                                      
c     mhordr4       ifne      prvord                                    
c                   z-add     0             phwtot                      
c     mhkey4        setll     pshipLL4                                  
c                   read      pshipLL4                                  
c* loop thru all orders in the ship table and add the weight to get a   
c* total weight per order #                                             
c                   dow       not %eof(pshipLL4)                        
c                   if        mhcmno4 = PHCOM# and                      
c                             mhordr4 = PHORD#                          
c* phwght is 11 char                                                    
c**                                                                     
c                   eval      prvord = mhordr4                          
c                   eval      phwtno = %dec(PHWGHT:7:2)                 
c                   add       phwtno        phwtot                      
c                   else                                          
c                   leave                                         
c                   endif                                         
c                   read      pshipLL4                            
c                   enddo                                         
c                   endif                                         

c                   endsr                               
 OUTPUT:    packages of course cannot be 0. 
05475731    0
05475731    0
05475731    0
05475731    0
05475731    0
05475731    0
05475731    0
05475731    0
05475731    0
05476179    0
05476179    0
05476179    0
05476179    0
05476179    0
05476179    0
05476179    0
05476179    0
05476179    0
05476179    0
05476179    0
05476179    0
05476179    0
05476179    0
05476179    0
05476179    0
05475736    0
05475736    0
05475736    0
05475736    0
05475736    0
05475736    0
05475736    0
05475736    0
05475736    0
05475736    0
05475750    0
05475750    0
05475750    0
05475750    0
05475750    0
05475750    0
```

Comment: What is the structure of `mhkey4`? How is it related to `mhordr4`?

Comment: This looks like one of those situations where putting compling your program in debug mode and then using STRDBG would help.  Also, what are the keys to PSHIPLL4?

Comment: keys are the company and order number.  here there is only 1 compaany

Comment: Then `mhkey4` is a DS or KLIST or somehow similar. Can you show how the program defines it and how the sub-field values are set? BTW, why would you use READ in this loop instead of READE? Also, I don't see any error checking nor do I see anything that checks whether or not the SETLL succeeded. How do know it works as you expect? That is, how do you know you're accessing the right records?

Comment: Nothing really stands out as the source of the problem.  This is definitely one of those situations where the debugger would show the real problem right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do this with SQL something like this:

```
exec sql
  with tmp as (
    select orderno, sum(weight) as orderweight
      from orderdetail
      group by orderno)
  select orderno, itemno, weight, orderweight
    into :localdatastructure
    from orderdetail
    join tmp using(orderno)
    where orderno = :localvariable;
```

where local variable is the order number you are processing, and local datastructure is a data structure defined to fit your output record.  You need to make sure you are only reading a single record at a time, or you can put this into a cursor to read multiple records.

Answer (score 3):

First off, consider replacing

```
c                   add       phwtno        phwtot
```

with

```
c                   eval      phwtot = phwtot + phwtno
```

or even

```
c                   eval      phwtot += phwtno
```

Doesn't change the results, but it is disconcerting to run into RPG III syntax in the middle of an RPG IV program.

I don't see any obvious logic issues.  Which means that the either:

- the values in `mhkey4` aren't what you expect; thus the `setll` and/or `read` aren't seeing the records you expect.
- the values in `mhcmno4, PHCOM#, mhordr4, PHORD#` aren't what you expect; thus the `if` is failing and you're never adding anything to `phwtot`
- the value in `PHWGHT` isn't what you're expect; thus the `%dec()` is returning 0.  I don't think it's failing as that should throw an exception.  Which BTW you should probably be monitoring for:

```
monitor;
  phwtno = %dec(PHWGHT:7:2);
on-error;
  //do something to handle the error
end-mon;
```

In any event, as Tracy suggested in a comment, running the program in debug and stepping through it is probably your best bet for figureing out what is going on.